# Android Studio VS Netbeans-> Print every array element

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I am new to Android studio. Just want to check how to get the results just like normal Netbeans when i run this coding

In Java netbeans

```
String[] words = {"tiger","lion","leopard"};  
  List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);  
  for (String e : wordList)  
  {  
     System.out.print(e+" 123 ");  

  }
```

I get results like this : tiger 123 lion 123 leopard 123

Then for results In Android Studio if I run this

```
String[] words = {"tiger","lion","leopard"};
    List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);
    String str1 = Arrays.toString(words);
    for (String e : wordList)
    {
        get_data.setText(str1+" 123 ");
    }
```

I get this : [tiger,lion,leopard]123

My question is how to list out the Array data just like normal Java (tiger 123 lion 123 leopard 123?

Comment: Why did you change the code in the first place?

Comment: The code is just not the same. Why are you joining the array there? If you want to add text to a textView use .append()

Comment: In the first one, you iterate on your array and print each element, in the second one you just convert the whole list as a string and display it. Check your loops, use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `get_data.setText(get_data.getText().toString()+e+" 123 ");` instant of `get_data.setText(str1+" 123 ")` .Because when you use `setText(String)` , it overwrite the previous data and set the new data you are gonna pass.

Answer (score -1):

```
String[] words = {"tiger","lion","leopard"};
List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);
String str1 = Arrays.toString(words);
String cache = "";
for (String e : wordList)
{
    cache+= get_data.setText(e+" 123 ");
}
```

this may help you